# Array of Picture boxes - now showing pictures (Visual Basic)

Tags: arrays, vb.net, picturebox

So, I have an array of picture boxes

```
Dim LocationArray(8,6) As PictureBox
```

I have set the array to pictures boxes as so

```
ArrayLocation(0,0)=pic00
ArrayLocation(0,1)=pic01
```

ect.

So, when the form loads, I want the picture box (3,0) to load with a picture in it

So far I have

```
LocationArray(3,0).Image = My.Recources.pic
```

And nothing happens when I load the form.

When I try to display a picture after changing which the coordinates of the array, I get a NullreferenceExepecation error.
How will I be able to fix this, the code I have so far is,

```
 Static xAxis As Integer = 3
    Static yAxis As Integer = 0
    LocationArray(xAxis, yAxis).Visible = False
    xAxis = +1
    LocationArray(xAxis, yAxis).Image = My.Resources.man
    LocationArray(yAxis, xAxis).Visible = True
```

Comment: What event are you using to run this code?

Comment: For 
LocationArray(3,0).Image = My.Recources.pic
I am using Form Load

And I am using a Button Click when trying to change the coordinates

Comment: In some places you have "LocationArray" and others you have "ArrayLocation".  Also, in the bottom two lines, you've swapped the position of the "xAxis" and "yAxis" variables in the last line?

Comment: You increment wrong. `xAxis = +1` is like saying _xAxis_ equals a positive number of 5. You should user the `+=` operator.

Comment: Duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)